# Weird callback call syntax (need explanation)

Tags: callback, rust, borrow-checker

The following example is a minimal example that I found that explains the problem I am having:

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::ops::DerefMut;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum ConnectionState {
    NotStarted,
}

type StateChangedCallback = Box<FnMut(ConnectionState) + Send + Sync>;

fn thread_func(mut on_state_changed: StateChangedCallback) {
    let new_state = ConnectionState::NotStarted;
    let f: &mut BorrowMut<StateChangedCallback> = &mut on_state_changed;
    f.borrow_mut().deref_mut()(new_state);
}

fn main() {
    let on_state_changed = Box::new(|new_state| {
        println!("New state: {:?}", new_state);
    });

    let join_handle = std::thread::spawn(|| thread_func(on_state_changed));

    join_handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

I have a simple thread that needs to call a callback passed from main. The callback is the signature `Box<FnMut(ConnectionState) + Send + Sync>`, since I want to call it multiple times. The only way I managed to call the callback was with this weird syntax:

```
let f: &mut BorrowMut<StateChangedCallback> = &mut on_state_changed;
f.borrow_mut().deref_mut()(new_state);
```

I searched and did not find a reasonable explanation for this. I am doing something wrong? Or is this the way Rust works?

If it is so, could someone explain the reason for this syntax?

Comment: I don't understand the question, `on_state_changed(new_state);` works, so does `let f = &mut on_state_changed; f(new_state);`.

Comment: Yes, I just explained the reason in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things.

You might explain, why you think, that you have to do `borrow_mut()`, since there is no borrowing involved in your signature.

Your function `thread_func` can be simplified to this:

```
fn thread_func(mut on_state_changed: StateChangedCallback) {
    let new_state = ConnectionState::NotStarted;
    on_state_changed(new_state);
}
```

Please note, that in contrast to your sentence *"I want to call it (the callback) multiple times"* you can't, because you move your closure into the function.

Comment: Well, my bad. I was fighting the borrow checker. I was changing things to make it compile and I added the `mut` on the parameter at the end, so I thought that the whole combination made the code compile and not only the `mut` in the parameter.

Comment: Regarding this comment `'I want to call it multiple times' you can't, since you move your closure into the function.`, I have a loop inside `thread_func` in my implementation, so this should work right?